# Hide the clicked button with the same method WinForm C#

Tags: c#, button

I've created a total of 27 buttons and 26 of them have a single clicked event. The other button which is not visible on form load will only be visible after the user clicked on one of the 26 buttons, then the clicked ones will be hidden in the form. Here's my method:

```
private void frmGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Click += clickHandler;
        btn2.Click += clickHandler;
        btn3.Click += clickHandler;
        btn4.Click += clickHandler;
        btn5.Click += clickHandler;
        btn6.Click += clickHandler;
        btn7.Click += clickHandler;
        btn8.Click += clickHandler;
        btn9.Click += clickHandler;
        btn10.Click += clickHandler;
        btn11.Click += clickHandler;
        btn12.Click += clickHandler;
        btn13.Click += clickHandler;
        btn14.Click += clickHandler;
        btn15.Click += clickHandler;
        btn16.Click += clickHandler;
        btn17.Click += clickHandler;
        btn18.Click += clickHandler;
        btn19.Click += clickHandler;
        btn20.Click += clickHandler;
        btn21.Click += clickHandler;
        btn22.Click += clickHandler;
        btn23.Click += clickHandler;
        btn24.Click += clickHandler;
        btn25.Click += clickHandler;
        btn26.Click += clickHandler;
    }

    private void clickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnCase.Text == "")
        {
            btnCase.Visible = true;
            // Selected button.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myGame.showAmount().ToString());
            myGame.removeAmount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem??

Comment: My guess problem is `(sender as Button)` instead of `btnCase`.

Comment: the one that I commented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
// Selected button.Visible = false;
```

write the following code

```
((Button)sender).Visible = false;
```